# Getting the first value from a list of values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table

```
ID  Name    Activity date   total time

1   AB       1/10/2015        209

1   AB       1/11/2015       1234

1   AB       1/12/2015        10

2   CD       1/10/2015       2347

2   CD       1/11/2015         0

2   CD       1/12/2015         0

2   CD       1/13/2015         5

3   EF       1/10/2015        53

3   EF       1/11/2015        14

4   XY       1/11/2015        76
```

I need the following result from it

```
ID  Name    Activity date   total time

1   AB       1/10/2015        209

2   CD       1/10/2015        2347

3   EF       1/10/2015        53

4   XY       1/11/2015        76
```

Basically, I need the first value for all the names, I used the below query but its giving blank for Name value

```
SELECT distinct(Id),
FIRST_VALUE(Name) OVER (ORDER BY Id Asc) AS Name,
FIRST_VALUE(ActivityDate) OVER (ORDER BY Id Asc) AS Date,
FIRST_VALUE(TimeInQueue) OVER (ORDER BY Id Asc) AS Totaltime
FROM Historytable
GROUP BY Id,ActivityDate,Name
```

Comment: What is the "first value" in your understanding?

Comment: That would return first value from a set of values.. am I wrong? :(

Comment: What however is the "first value"?  The earliest ActivityDate for a ID/Name?

Comment: Vaibhav means for all the values that have the same Name, take the first one.

Comment: Yes Z, correct, for name having AB, take the first record, similarly for other names

Comment: But what is the first record? Ordered by what? Date?

Comment: Issue is resolved, thanks David, i did some changes on adding order by Date too,

Comment: Thanks Z for the help:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Window function`

```
SELECT ID,
       NAME,
       [Activity date],
       total time
FROM   (SELECT Row_number() OVER(partition BY Id ORDER BY [Activity date]) Rn,
               ID,
               NAME,
               [Activity date],
               [total  time] from yourtable) A
WHERE  rn = 1
```

or  find the `min [Activity date]` date per `id` and join the result back to the table using `Id` and `[Activity date]`

```
SELECT a.ID,
       a.NAME,
       a.[Activity date],
       a.[total time]
FROM   yourtable A
       JOIN (SELECT Min([Activity date]) [Activity date],
                    ID
             FROM   yourtable) B
         ON a.id = b.id
            AND a.[Activity date] = b.[Activity date]
```